# MQTT Receive Message in C++

Tags: c++, mqtt, publish, subscribe

I'm trying to receive messages from a published topic in C++. I know in Java it's just `client.on('message', (topic, message))`. But I couldn't do something like that in a C++ library. How can I do it?

As of now, I've got everything set up and am subscribing to the topic I'm interested in, but I'm stuck on how to fetch the message from there.

```
MQTTClient client;

void mqtt_subscribe(std::string const &topic) {

  if(!mqtt_initialized) {
    return;
  }

  MQTTClient_subscribe(client, topic.c_str(), 1);
}
```

Comment: You could avoid the negation, avoid the premature return, avoid the return statement, reduce the number of (real) lines, and get better readability - all at the same time.

Comment: You haven't said which MQTT client library you are using, edit the question to include that information. Also the "example" you've posted looks more like Javascript than Java (which are VERY different)

Answer (score 0):

Your client is connected to nothing, so you have to connect first by calling the Mqtt client constructor of the mosquitopp library witch is the top level cpp interface.